# Concatenate .Wav file by their header into 1 Temp File

Tags: c#, concatenation, wav, temporary-files

How do i concatenate .Wav files's header into one Temp file. I am trying to merge multiple segments of Telephone call. And in Database this all Segments will have same call ID because it is one call but multiple segments.

Answer (score 3):

See this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio

The relevant part is the class `WAVFile.cs` - the merging of two WAV files is implemented in its method `MergeAudioFiles` (line 1326).

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/gentisaliu/1b126994ff4644d5d95a) contains `WAVFile.cs`. Other things which are useful:

- The header of a WAV file is created inside the `Create` method (starting from line 441, as per the WAV format specification, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#RIFF_WAVE) or [the full specification](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/Docs/riffmci.pdf))
- the header of a WAV file is read/loaded in the `Open` method (line 93).
- you can set additional metadata in the optional `INFO` section, http://www.robotplanet.dk/audio/wav_meta_data has a pretty nice overview. This is not implemented in the class referenced above.

To create a temporary file ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

Comment: Thank you Genti Saliu, for helping me out.

Comment: No problem. I had posted the wrong CodeProject link in the previous version of the answer, it's fixed now.